# Understanding printf function with * format

Tags: c

```
char **w = c->u.word;
printf ("%*s%s", indent, "", *w);
```

Ok, currently, `*w` holds `"true"` as a string value.
And I have no problem accessing it.
indent is integer value, which is 2.

First, I don't understand how printf function works in this case. It looks like it has four arguments.
Second, I expected the output as 'true', but I got nothing. why does it behave like this?

Comment: give it a try with different values for `indent` you will get it

Comment: Could you explain what exactly this printf function do?

Comment: [Check this code](http://codepad.org/HPqLiuXJ) and it's output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The asterisk (*) means you can define a variable field width. So

```
"%*s%s"
```

Means you have a string with a variable field width (the length of the field is passed as an integer before the string is to `printf`). That is followed by a string which will be printed with no padding.

Your parameters are:

```
indent, "", *w
```

In the format, `indent` corresponds to the asterisk (`*`), `""` corresponds to the `s` in the `%*s`, and `*w` corresponds do the `%s`. So this will print a zero-length string with a field width of `indent` followed by the string that `*w` points to. In other words, you'll always get `indent` spaces in front of the string `*w` in the output.

Comment: This is what I really want to hear. Thank you for clear explanation!

Comment: @user1798211 in answer to your other question of why `""` and not `" "`... you could do either. But if you do `" "`, that will have a one-space width, then you'd need to pass `indent-1` for the `%*s` to get a total indent of `indent`. `""` is cleaner and expresses the intent better.

Comment: I see, now I am clear on the * and "" part. By the way, why don't I get the "true" as a output?

Comment: @user1798211, if `*w` really is the *pointer* to the string `"true"`, then you should see `true` on the output. If you aren't getting `true` on the output, then maybe that condition isn't true and you'd have to show some code on how it's set to determine what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%10s","Hello");
```

this will print hello with width 10 and it is Right aligned.

```
printf("%*s",10,"Hello");  //is same  as above
```

`printf ("%*s%s", indent, "", *w);`

This will print indent number of spaces before printing string which is pointed by `*w`

Comment: Wait, why do we represent the space as "" instead of " "?

Comment: you can also represent like that. Assume indent is 3 and `" "` if we don't use indent it will print only one space.if we use indent ,it should print 3 characters.so two extra spaces will be added before space.and if you use `""` this wont print anything so three spaces will print because of indent.and see with using `"a"` or `"abc"` instead of `"" or " "`.

Comment: Do you know why don't I get the value of *w printed out? I know it holds the value since I inspect this value with gdb.

Comment: add printf where ever you want to see `*w` value check whether is it giving correct value or not. if not then problem with your code. and also check simply `printf("%*s%s",10,"","true");`

Comment: printf("%s",*w);
printf ("%*s%s", indent, "", "true");
prints out nothing.

Comment: @user1798211, try what Gangadhar suggested with a `10` instead of `indent` to make sure there's a value there (just for debug purposes). Also, try putting a `\n` at the end of your format (`"%*s%s\n"`) so that the output buffer is flushed, just to be sure.

Comment: I figured out that next statement of printf gets infinity loop, and that prevents printf to be represented on the output screen. Thank you anyway!